# Upload an XML file to Java backend in Spring

Tags: java, angular, xml, spring, typescript

I have an HTML page like this:

```
<table class="generate-full-width">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" width="100%">
            <strong>* Upload the License XML file here. *</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <br><br><br>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="5">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" style='margin-right:auto' (click)="selectFile()">File Upload</button>
            <input #fileUploadInput type="file" id="fileUpload" hidden name="avatar" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
            <br><br>
            <a class="generate-full-width" style="color: darkred;" *ngIf="fileName"><strong>{{fileName}}</strong></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

The component.ts for this is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'upload-license-file-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'upload-license-file.html',
})

export class uploadFileDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddProductDialog>,
    private generateLicenseService: GeneratelicenseService,
    private builder: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {
  }

  @ViewChild('fileUploadInput', {static: false})
  fileUploadVariable: ElementRef;
  fileName;
  filesToUpload = [];

  resetFile(){
    this.fileUploadVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
  }

  
  selectFile(){
    this.resetFile();
    let el: HTMLElement = this.fileUploadVariable.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    el.click();
  }

  fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    let file = fileInput.target.files[0]
    console.log(file)
    console.log(file.toString());
    this.filesToUpload = [];
    this.filesToUpload.push(file);
    this.fileName = file['name'];
  }

  
}
```

Right now I cannot do anything with the file. How can I upload the file to the backend, maybe save ot in a temporary location, so that at backend I can parse this file.The backend is Java. Please help.

Comment: Well, this should be a normal multipart file upload. There should be plenty of tutorials on how to do that in Angular and Spring rest controllers (those might be independent but file uploads are pretty standard so just implement both sides and it should work).

Comment: For the front-end mostly I am getting tutorials, but for the backend, I am still stuck

Comment: What's so hard for the backend? Here's the first result of a quick search for "spring file upload" which should cover what you need to upload the file: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ . Once you've uploaded the file you can use it in whatever way you need, e.g. move it around, parse it, etc.